Display Related Name in Lookup Field After Selection Without Saving to Database in d365 fo
I have a form in Dynamics 365 Finance & Operations where I want to dynamically display related data in a lookup field after making a selection, without actually saving the display value to the database. Here's a simplified example:
In this grid, I have:
A field called reportToPosition that uses a lookup for selecting an ID.
Another field called StakeholderNameDisplay that displays the name related to the selected ID.
Objective:
When a user selects a value in the reportToPosition field (like HS03-000014), I want the form to display the related name (like "moderator") in the same field, but without saving this display value back to the database. I only want to keep the selected ID (e.g., HS03-000014) saved in the database, not the name.
Is there a way to represent this display functionality directly in the lookup field or in a single control? Essentially, I'm looking for a way to dynamically show the name related to the selected ID in the reportToPosition field itself, without overriding the saved ID.
What I Tried:
I set up a display method in the related table to fetch the name based on the ID, and it works in showing the related name in a separate field (StakeholderNameDisplay). However, I’d prefer to display this dynamically in the same reportToPosition dropdown.
Example Display:
Currently, I have this:



Role Code
Title
Description
reportToPosition
StakeholderNameDisplay




HS03-000011
CEO
CEO Manager
N/A
N/A


HS03-000012
CTO
CTO Manager
HS03-000013
Project Sponsor


HS03-000013
Project Sponsor
Project Sponsor
HS03-000014
Moderator


HS03-000014
Moderator
Moderator
HS03-000012
CTO



In this example, I'd like reportToPosition to show the name (like "moderator") upon selection but retain the ID as the actual saved value.
Additional Context:
I need this setup to work across related tables but simplified this example to focus on the main issue.
and i need as in one table i had more than three lookup so making a display method for every one and put it besides the lookup wouldn't be good in interface .
Thanks in advance for any guidance or solutions!

Look into surrogate, alternate and replacement keys, e.g. https://community.dynamics.com/blogs/post/?postid=8b838920-b717-4ccf-91f0-6a3bc3ee13df
I would also recommend you do not use the dynamics-crm tag on questions about D365 FO. Microsoft markets those as kinda the same thing, but from a technological point of view, they are very different.
